# celery - Task is not running despite being registered. Celery console does not reflect reception of task

Tags: python, django, docker, celery

After reviewing many many threads on the same issue, I have found no answer yet.

I'm running a Django app with the following things

**Python**: 3.6

**Django: 3.0.5**

**Celery: 4.0.2**

**Kombu: 4.2.0**

I'm running all the stack with docker-compose, celery is running in a different container.
Apparently my task is registering within celery, because if I inspect the registered tasks of my application I get a list with a single element, the task itself:

```sh
$ celery -A apps.meals.tasks inspect registered
-> celery@7de3143ddcb2: OK
    * apps.meals.tasks.send_slack_notification
```

`myproj/settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'apps',
    'apps.meals',
]
```

`myproj/celery.py`:

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import Celery
import os
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproj.settings')

app = Celery('myproj')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()

app.conf.update(
    BROKER_URL=settings.BROKER_URL,
)
```

My task is in a different place, within the `meals` app, in a file named `tasks.py`.

`apps/meals/tasks.py`

```py
from django.conf import settings
from slackclient import SlackClient
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
from myproj import celery_app
from json import loads, dumps

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)


slack_markdown_text = "Hola!\n El menu de hoy es:\n {content}\n Pueden enviar su pedido aca: {link}\n Saludos!"


@celery_app.task(name="apps.meals.tasks.send_slack_notification")
def send_slack_notification(serial_menu, serial_options):
  ...
```

My file structure is like:

```
technical-tests/
|
|--apps/
|----*snap
|----meals/
|------*snap
|------tasks.py
|--myproj
|----*snap
|----celery.py
|----settings.py
```

Finally, docker-compose.yml goes like this:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
   backend: ....
   celery:
       build: 
         context: ..
         dockerfile: ./deploy/Dockerfile
       volumes:
         - ../code/:/opt/somelocation
       environment:
         - SECRET_KEY
         - SLACK_TOKEN
         - SLACK_CHANNEL
         - SLACK_URL_PATTERN
         - BROKER_URL
       command: celery -A apps.meals.tasks worker -l info
       depends_on: 
         - backend
         - redis
```

**Celery worker console**:

The Celery console when starts DOESN'T show that pretty colored screen when the registered tasks appear, so that's suspicious. It only shows:

```sh
celery_1_aa9c50e916ae | /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/platforms.py:796: RuntimeWarning: You're running the worker with superuser privileges: this is
celery_1_aa9c50e916ae | absolutely not recommended!
celery_1_aa9c50e916ae | 
celery_1_aa9c50e916ae | Please specify a different user using the --uid option.
celery_1_aa9c50e916ae | 
celery_1_aa9c50e916ae | User information: uid=0 euid=0 gid=0 egid=0
celery_1_aa9c50e916ae | 
celery_1_aa9c50e916ae |   uid=uid, euid=euid, gid=gid, egid=egid,
celery_1_aa9c50e916ae | [2020-04-08 14:05:34,024: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://redis:6379/0
celery_1_aa9c50e916ae | [2020-04-08 14:05:34,034: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
celery_1_aa9c50e916ae | [2020-04-08 14:05:35,053: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
celery_1_aa9c50e916ae | [2020-04-08 14:05:35,068: WARNING/MainProcess] /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/fixups/django.py:200: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never use this setting in production environments!
celery_1_aa9c50e916ae |   warnings.warn('Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never '
celery_1_aa9c50e916ae | [2020-04-08 14:05:35,069: INFO/MainProcess] celery@7de3143ddcb2 ready.
```

I know the task is not running because in python shell when I call `send_slack_notifications` **without** `delay` it runs immediately, but when I use `delay` the commands hangs forever and the celery console doesn't move, like it doesn't receives any information.

Any insight is much appreciated!

**UPDATE**

The `delay` call is being made in `apps/meals/views.py`

```py
from apps.meals.tasks import send_slack_notification

@login_required
def notify_menu(request, uuid):
    if is_staff(request.user):
        menu = Menu.objects.filter(uuid=uuid)
        send_slack_notification.delay(
            serialize(menu),
            serialize(menu.first().list_options())
        )
```

Comment: Please include your code that you're using to trigger the task as well as the full output from the worker.

Comment: hey @schillingt I have added the view function that calls the task. As the full output, it has already been posted. That's all there is.

Comment: There's typically more instantiation output for a celery worker indicating the queue and exchange involved.

Comment: Have you tried creating a simple `add` task that takes two ints to see if that runs?

Comment: @schillingt Yes, I have seen it. I finally reverted some folder structure changes with the Django applications and it seemed to work again.

Answer (score 1):

1. In your celery config, add the environment variable `C_FORCE_ROOT` with a value of `1`.
2. Use `CELERY_BROKER_URL` in django settings to properly set the celery broker from settings and do not pass in `BROKER_URL` from the environment (celery will be confused because the environment variable may override the setting variable.
3. Don't set the `BROKER_URL` using `app.conf.update`, use the setting `CELERY_BROKER_URL` as discussed above.